# Identity database won't save value in EF Core 7

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am having trouble updating a guid value in my identity database, using a value I pull from my main database. I have split the databases out so there is a user database and a main database for security reasons. Due to this i am storing a custom guid value to reference a company id in my identity database to link a user to a company.

When I try to update the `CompanyId` value in my identity database, nothing errors, the variables look fine but the value does not get updated to the database.

I am using Entity Framework Core 7 and Razor pages. I have scaffolded Identity into the application.

Here is my `User` class:

```
using CustomerPortal.DataModels;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace CustomerPortal.Areas.Identity.Data;

// Add profile data for application users by adding properties to the CustomerPortalUser class
public class CustomerPortalUser : IdentityUser
{
    [PersonalData]
    public string FullName { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    [PersonalData]
    public byte[]? ProfilePicture { get; set; }
    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public Company? Company { get; set; }

    public bool isCompanyContact = false;

    public string? CompanyName()
    {
        return this.Company?.Name;
    }
}
```

Here is my Razor page:

```
@page
@model CustomerPortal.Pages.Admin.AppUsers.EditUserDetailsModel
@using CustomerPortal.Areas.Identity.Data;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject UserManager<CustomerPortalUser> userManager

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Application Users";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

    string redirectPath = Request.Path + "?id=" + Model.ClickedUser.Id;
}

<h1>Edit user: @Model.ClickedUser.FullName</h1>

<hr />

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ClickedUser.Email" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ClickedUser.Email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ClickedUser.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <!--added code to use a variable from the model here-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Company</label>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <select class="dropdown-item" asp-for="ClickedUser.CompanyId" asp-items="Model.CompaniesList"></select>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Admin/Companies/Create?redir=@redirectPath">Create New Company</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" style="margin-top:20px">
                <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-page="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

Here is the Razor page controller:

```
using CustomerPortal.Areas.Identity.Data;
using CustomerPortal.Data;
using CustomerPortal.DataModels;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace CustomerPortal.Pages.Admin.AppUsers
{
    public class EditUserDetailsModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly CustomerPortalDataContext _context;
        private readonly UserManager<CustomerPortalUser> _userManager;
        private readonly CustomerPortalUserContext _userContext;

        public List<SelectListItem> CompaniesList { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public CustomerPortalUser ClickedUser { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public EditUserDetailsModel(CustomerPortalDataContext context, UserManager<CustomerPortalUser> userManager, CustomerPortalUserContext userContext)
        {
            _userContext = userContext;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _context = context;
            GetCompanies();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet(Guid? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            //Get the user that was clicked using the user id
            ClickedUser = await _userContext.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id.ToString());

            if (ClickedUser == null)
            {
                RedirectToPage("./Index");
            }

            //Input = new InputModel
            //{
            //    CompanyId = id
            //};

            return Page();
        }

       
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        //var user = await _userContext.Users.SingleAsync(x => x.Id == ClickedUser.Id.ToString());
        //ModelState.Remove("CustomerPortalUser.Company");

        //if(id == null)
        //{
        //    return NotFound();
        //}

        //var userToUpdate = await _userContext.Users.FindAsync(id);

        //if (userToUpdate == null) 
        //{
        //    return NotFound();
        //}

        //if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<CustomerPortalUser>(
        //    userToUpdate,
        //    "CompanyId",
        //    c => c.CompanyId))
        //{
        //    await _userContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        //    return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        //}

        //assign Company based on id sent from form (required field)
        ClickedUser.CompanyId = _context.Companies.Single(c => c.Id == ClickedUser.CompanyId).Id;

        await _userContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        await _userManager.UpdateAsync(ClickedUser);


        //if(Input.CompanyId != user.CompanyId)
        //{
        //    user.CompanyId = Input.CompanyId;
        //}

        //await _userManager.UpdateAsync(ClickedUser);
        //await _userContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }

        public void GetCompanies()
        {
            CompaniesList = _context.Companies.Select(x => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Value = x.Id.ToString(),
                Text = x.Name
            }).ToList();
        }

        public class InputModel
        {
            public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

In the controller you can see the the commented out lines of the different methods I have tried to do this.

I have tried:

- Emulating the scaffolded EF Core set with Input and InputModel
- Setting the Id value
- Setting the company value
- Setting the way it indicates on the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/update-related-data?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

------EDIT-----

I have changed the code above to my closest working version (the razor page and the onPost method)

Debug looks like this:
[image: ClickedUser]

The DbContext upon debug:
[image: DbContext]

Comment: Why is `Company` `[NotMapped]`? And what happens in `TryUpdateModelAsync`?

Comment: I updated the guid successfully on myside ,please show more details of the dbcontext and the sql command when you debug

Comment: This code saves nothing if `TryUpdateModelAsync` returns `false`. What does that method do? Where is `userToUpdate` modified?

Comment: The current code doesn't seem to modify the user, so there's nothing to store. EF Core doesn't need complex methods and abstractions. You load an object or objects,  modify their properties and then call `SaveChanges` at the end. EF Core itself will detect all the changes and generate the SQL needed to save them to the database. All you need to change CompnayId is to call `userToUpdate.CompanyId = Input.CompanyId` before calling `SaveChanges`

Comment: @GertArnold The Company value is not mapped because I use that for retrieval. The companyId value is mapped as it's the only value I want to store in the database.

Comment: @RuikaiFeng I have added an editted version. Is there anything in perticular you want me to expand in the debug menu?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This version was the Microsoft method which to be honest I didn't fully understand. Please see the edited version now posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dbcontext would be registed as Scoped(per request) by default,the context in your `OnGet` Method is not the same instance with that in your `OnPost` method,you have to load it again before you update it

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(ClickedUser.Email??"")??default!;
user.CompanyId = ClickedUser.CompanyId;
await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
```

A minimal example here:

```
    [BindProperty]
    public CustomerPortalUser ClickedUser { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> CompaniesList { get; set; }

    

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet(string id)
    {
        ClickedUser = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id)??default!;
        CompaniesList =_context.Company.Select(....).ToList() ;
        return Page();
    }

    
    

    
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(ClickedUser.Email??"")??default!;
        user.CompanyId = ClickedUser.CompanyId;
        await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
```

Page:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ClickedUser.Email" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ClickedUser.Email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ClickedUser.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                
            </div>
            <!--added code to use a variable from the model here-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Company</label>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <select class="dropdown-item" asp-for="ClickedUser.CompanyId" asp-items="Model.CompaniesList"></select>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" style="margin-top:20px">
                <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <a asp-page="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]